# Are optional protocols from Objective-C not something that should be done in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, swift, protocols

In Objective-C it's a pretty common paradigm to use conforming to a protocol and setting a delegate to allow two objects to communicate with one another. Part of this is optional protocols that they don't *have* to implement.

It seems Swift doesn't really consider this a part of its language. It has protocols but in order to mark a method in a protocol as optional the protocol needs an `objc` prefix, telling me that it's also an Objective-C relic?

Is there something we should be doing instead that is more Swift-esque? Passing fancy closures or something?

Comment: My assumption has always been that this is something missing from the language.

Comment: @Lance As in something yet to be implemented, or purposefully omitted?

Comment: I would assume purposefully omitted, the same as interfaces.

Comment: @DougSmith I assume yet to be implemented, but maybe that's wishful thinking :)

Comment: @Zaph protocols *are* interfaces or is there some distinction I'm missing?

Comment: No, they are different. Notice that Objective-C has both and they are used differently. Interfaces describe implemented methods, protocols describe to-be implemented methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [this Developer Forums topic](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1051388):

> Optional methods in protocols are limited to @objc protocols only because we haven't implemented them in native protocols yet. **This is something we plan to support**.

---

Although you **can** implement delegate pattern with optional methods in pure Swift, but it's very ugly ...

```
protocol MyOperationDelegate:class {
    var operation:Optional<(MyOperation, didComplete:Bool) -> Void> { get }
}

class MyOperation {
    weak var delegate:MyOperationDelegate?

    func start() {
        println("started")
        self.delegate?.operation?(self, didComplete:true)
    }
}

class Operator:MyOperationDelegate {

    func doOperate() {
        let operation = MyOperation()
        operation.delegate = self
        operation.start()
    }

    var operation:((MyOperation, didComplete:Bool) -> Void)? { return self._operation }
    func _operation(operation:MyOperation, didComplete:Bool) {
        println("operation: \(operation) didComplete:\(didComplete)")
    }
}

let op = Operator()
op.doOperate()
```

and you cannot declare multiple similar delegate method names:

```
protocol MyOperationDelegate {
    var operation:Optional<(MyOperation, didComplete:Bool) -> Void> { get }
    var operation:Optional<(MyOperation, inProgress:) -> Void> { get }
//      ^ [!] Invalid redeclaration of 'operation'
}
```

Comment: Swift: very ugly, got it.